# Redirect a page to index in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a page to index.php. When I click on a link , it redirects to something like `http://example.com/article.php` which doesn't exist yet. As it doesn't exist, I want to redirect to index.php.

I tried something like :

```
RewriteRule ^article.\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [R=301]
```

This code redirect to index.php but with every link on the site and not only with `article.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?:^|/)article\.php$ /index.php? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ensures that redirect only happens if `index.php` is not a valid file in your system.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work, I have a 404 error page :/

Comment: It is at the top of the htaccess, and the url is example.com/fr/article.php?mid=2&msid=0&menu_id=2&rid=2&lg=fr and it doesn't redirect, it's just a 404 error on the same page